# Xamarin: missing System.Diagnostics.Process missing

Tags: xamarin, process, system.diagnostics

I want to use System.Diagnostics.Process functionality, but Process class is not a part of System.Diagnostics namespace. Is there some magic to show this class and be able to use it?

Is there any other way to call cmd commands from code?

Thanks

Comment: what specifically are you trying to do, and on which platform?  Most mobile devices prohibit the kind of low level activity that you might be trying.

Comment: I want to call command for start VPN software from code. It's UWP application

Comment: `Process` is not supported on UWP, if the VPN you need to start supports application protocols, you can use `LaunchUriForResultsAsync`